# Reading inputs from moisture sensor is only giving me 0s and 1s but I want a bigger span

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I'm currently reading values from a moisture sensor with this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
print "testing"
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    input_value = GPIO.input(14)
    print input_value
```

This is giving me values of 0 and 1 if its dry or not dry. But I want it to span a greater range. For instance the same setup on my arduino gives a span between 1023 and 0.

How can I get my code to read values in a greater range so I can set breakpoints for different soil levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Arduinos the Pi has no analogue input GPIO.

If you want to read an analogue value you will have to add an ADC (Analogue to Digital Converter).

The MCP3XXX series are quite popular, e.g. the MCP3008 is an ADC with 8 channels and 10 bit resolution, the MCP3202 is an ADC with 2 channels and 12 bit resolution.